# How to fill in this popup using selenium in python? When right clicked, inspect option is not seen

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, popupwindow

below is a screenshot of a local website. I tried finding the XPath, switching the window but the user input couldn't be done. Help needed.

[popup image][image: 1]

Comment: Always share your code here. Otherwise the question will be down voted/closed. Show what you have tried.

Comment: thank you for the information. I was also wondering the same about how did I get so many downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not an alert , its a browser level window you cannot handle it from selenium. You should use any other tool like silkuli, autoit etc

you can also authenticate directly from url to avoid that pop up as :

if your url was like

https://www.yoururl.com

change it as:

```
url = "https://username:password@yoururl.com"
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign